# Java custom annotation creation

Tags: java, annotations

I want to create custom annotation that trims the value of a string. I have tried below code.

**Main class (where main method exist):**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        @Anno(removeSpace = "aaa")
        String a = "   p   ";

        System.err.println(a);

    }
}
```

**Custom annotation:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE)
public @interface Anno {

    String removeSpace() default "";

    //I want to write code here but how ??

}
```

I have watched results in stack overflow but did not understood.

Comment: You are misunderstood how annotations work. You should read more about it baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation

Comment: I have read the above tutorial they have given an existing annotation example. Can you provide any tutorial that explain from basic? @ekiryuhin